# How do i just print the final list result rather than the previous lists too?

Tags: python, list, printing

As the title suggests,

```
def multiples_of_3(x, y):
    y = y + 1
    storage_list = []
    for i in range(x, y):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            storage_list.append(i)
            print(storage_list)
```

multiples_of_3(3, 9)

Comment: un-indent the line `print(storage_list)` out of the `for`-loop. otherwise, each iteration of the `for`-loop will print the current result.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with Sublime Text, it prints out [3]
[3, 6]
[3, 6, 9]

Comment: Thanks davedwards !

Comment: it's nothing to do with sublime text, that result is expected for python code. however, align `print(storage_list)` with the `for` line, and you'll get the expected behavior of one line output

Comment: I see! Sorry still quite new to programming but getting there thanks to your help :)

Comment: glad to help, keep practicing and asking when you get stuck, that's how we all learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `print(storage_list)` outside of forloop

```
In [3]: def multiples_of_3(x, y):
   ...:     y = y + 1
   ...:     storage_list = []
   ...:     for i in range(x, y):
   ...:         if i % 3 == 0:
   ...:             storage_list.append(i)
   ...:     print(storage_list)
   ...:
   ...:

In [4]: multiples_of_3(3, 9)
[3, 6, 9]

In [5]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I the following is what you want:

```
def multiples_of_3(x, y):
    y = y + 1
    storage_list = []
    for i in range(x, y):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            storage_list.append(i)
    print(storage_list)

multiples_of_3(3, 9)
```

You just need to bring out the print statement to outside the if and the for loop so it prints only when both those statements are done executing.

Comment: [Please format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Glad to help. All the best! :)